# moving background with the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, web

I'm trying to build a website in wordpress that have a moving background. I can move the background now but the content on the website is stuck in the same place, it doesn't move. The background does not move with the scrollbar and the content.

So my question is, is there a way that I could put a content on that website that will be stuck to the background like on this chanel website? http://www.chanel.com/en_US/fashion.html

thanks.

Comment: Point one is, where is your code? Point two, it might be that I'm still a bit blind at this time, but where do you see moving background on your linked page?

Comment: here is what i have so far http://tomase10.co.nf/index/. If the link page are not using a moving background do you have an idea what they are using ? and how i can ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need backgorund. 
Create background div with your background with absolute position, overflow: hidden,  and set it as you need.
Create dive with content with fixed position. 
And change your background div position with scrolls moving using css transitions.

Answer (score 0):

simply make two divs like :

```
<div class="1" style="position:absolute;">
   <div class="2" style="position:fixed;"></div>        
</div>
```

now add draggable plugin from jquery to div class="1" and  add your content to div class="2". It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I changed placement of divs :

```
<div class="bg-img" id="draggable">            
</div>
<div class="divFix">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.</p>
    </div>
```

look here : [follow link for solution](http://jsfiddle.net/richapandey/Vq9Bj/1/)